# Difference between two code snippets output, Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

I have working on some python3 on hackerrank (basic python3) and comes to this problem [String Validators](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-validators/problem). I have written two code snippets where the first one provided Wrong Answer but the second one was accepted. Even though, they both provided the same output. FYI, my first code snippet did not even pass the Sample Test Cases.

Code Snippet One:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    if str(s).isalnum():
        print(True)
    else:
        success = False
        for ch in s:
            if ch.isalnum():
                success = True
                print(True)
        if not success:
            print(False)

    if str(s).isalpha():
        print(True)
    else:
        success = False
        for ch in s:
            if ch.isalpha():
                success = True
                print(True)
        if not success:
            print(False)


    if str(s).isdigit():
        print(True)
    else:
        success = False
        for ch in s:
            if ch.isdigit():
                success = True
                print(True)
        if not success:
            print(False)

    if str(s).islower():
        print(True)
    else:
        success = False
        for ch in s:
            if ch.islower():
                success = True
                print(True)
        if not success:
            print(False)

    if str(s).isupper():
        print(True)
    else:
        success = False
        for ch in s:
            if ch.isupper():
                success = True
                print(True)
        if not success:
            print(False)
```

Code Snippet Two: **[The accepted one]**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    print (any(c.isalnum() for c in s))
    print (any(c.isalpha() for c in s))
    print (any(c.isdigit() for c in s))
    print (any(c.islower() for c in s))
    print (any(c.isupper() for c in s))
```

Both of these code snippets answer is same: Five True in Five new lines. What went wrong on the first snippet? 
[I did not know about the pythons any function before]
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: These two codes are not equal. Already in the first loop you print a boolean for each ch in s - far more than just five true in five lines. Perhaps the output is equal just in case _if_ s is a string which leads to true in _all_ five tests. Just try a different input which does not...

Comment: @SpghttCd, Yes. Sorry my bad. That was some error in logic!!!